# Any current issues on SoftLayer side with Object Storage ordering or provisioning?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there some issue currently with SoftLayer handling Object Storage order or provisioning one?  I am using same code that I've used before to submit an order for an Object Storage.  I can see the Billing Item showing up in SoftLayer side.  But the "Detail" column is empty.  When it worked before, the "Detail" column has value like "IBMOS892833-5".

I have a logic in my code to determine whether my order is completed by looking at the detail of Billing Item (transactionStatus.name value).  When it doesn't work, it seems that the status is stuck at "SERVICE REGISTER" like this:

```
"transactionStatus":{"averageDuration":"1.91","friendlyName":"Register a network service","name":"SERVICE REGISTER"}
```

This is the type of call that I made to get the billing item status:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/85029623/getObject.json?objectMask=provisionTransaction;provisionTransaction.transactionStatus;provisionTransaction.transactionGroup;provisionTransaction.pendingTransactions;provisionTransaction.hardware
```

I know that when it worked it had "COMPLETE" status.
Two days ago (Feb. 16) in the morning, I was having same problem and once or twice, it worked properly, then back to having same issue later with being stuck at "SERVICE REGISTER" status.

Did the SoftLayer_Billing_Item::getObject() changed what it returns for the transactionStatus.name attribute?   So that maybe I should take "SERVICE REGISTER" as the provision complete status now?  Or is SoftLayer having some issue with handling Object Storage order?  I've contacted SoftLayer support and they tell me everything looked good but sometimes it just doesn't show in the Object Storage list.  Although the one I ordered doesn't show in the Object Storage list, my problem is not about not about that.  I think the Object Storage provisioning seems to be having some issues.  I tried to order Object Storage through SoftLayer customer portal and I see the same thing.  It does not show up in the Object Storage list and the billing item detail continue to show "SERVICE REGISTER" status.

Can someone tell me what's going on?
My code issue? or Is something going wrong on SoftLayer side?
In case some of you have access to check, this is the billing ID that I ordered from SoftLayer customer portal web site:  85041591.
And this is the billing ID that I ordered from my code:  85029623

Comment: It seems there is an issue in the provisioning process (Transaction). You need to submit a ticket in order that someone from SoftLayer can solve this issue. By the way, you are right, the "transactionStatus" must be "Complete", once the provisioning process would finished.

Answer (score 1):

Well the provisioning process runs automatically, but sometimes there are issues in your provisioning and the softlayer's guys have to review what happened and fixed, that's why sometimes the order take long time to be completed. If you order takes too long to be completed you need to submit a ticket and ask them what is going on.